# file not found error in shell script called from Automator

Tags: macos, automator, script

I want a shortcut to a script that merge video and audio.

If I go in terminal to the directory documents/convert and run the script with ./script.sh everything works. If I copy the script in automator I got error *.mp4 not found.

This is the script. I just want to click an icon to run the script.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
Cd "/Users/Tom/Documents/Convert"
for filename in *.mp4; do
    stub="${filename%.*}"
    /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i "${stub}.mp4" -i "${stub}.wav" -c:v copy -c:a aac -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0 "${stub}_crf".mp4
done
```

Comment: `Cd` in the beginning won't work, it should be lower-case : `cd`.

Comment: I'm trying to check if ${stub}_ok exists and rename it to ${stub}_ok01. Thats works but now I want to check if ${stub}_ok01 exists and create ${stub}_ok02 :#!/bin/bash
now=$(date +"%d_%m_%Y_%Hu%M")
cd "/Users/tomvanwinkel/Documents/Convert/Merge"
for filename in *.mp4; do
    stub="${filename%.*}"
/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i "${stub}.mp4" -i "${stub}.wav" -c:v copy -c:a aac -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0 "${stub}_ok".mp4

FILE="${stub}_ok".mp4
if [ -f "$FILE" ]; then
    cp "${stub}_ok".mp4 "${stub}_ok01".mp4
fi

done

Comment: I suggest you create a new question for that.